# AWS Cost Explorer: What USE1 Bundle usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services

What is USE1 Bundle Usage in AWS. I googled the term, but i did not find anything useful. I just found, that it is causing costs in my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE1 Bundle Usage Is used to specify you had expenses while running [Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-your-amazon-lightsail-bill) in the us-east-1 region

Comment: And how do i know that? Is there a "bundle usage" means "lightsail" table, so i do not need to ask for the next term.